# Recreating a ComboBox's DisplayMemberPath in a Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a custom WPF control (CheckedListComboBox) that allows a user to select one or more options from a list. Essentially the user opens a dropdown-style control and checks off the items they would like to select. When the user checks or unchecks an option in the list, the main (non-popup) area of the control is updated to reflect the choices the user has made.

Here's an example of the control in action:

[image]

I am mostly satisfied with the state of the control, but there is one piece I would like to improve and I'm unsure of how to proceed.

The generation of the text that reflects the user's choice(s) currently relies on calling `ToString` on each of the selected items. This is fine in the example case above, as all of the objects I've passed to the control are strings. However, if I passed in a custom object that didn't override `ToString`, I would simply get the fully qualified class of the object (e.g. `MyNamespace.MyObject`).

What I would like to do is implement something akin to a WPF ComboBox's `DisplayMemberPath` property, where I can simply specify the property to display in the TextBox area of the control for each selected item.

I could just be lazy and go about this via Reflection, but I'm aware that this may not be the fastest (performance-wise) approach.

Here are the options I've considered so far:

**Force all bound items to implement a specific interface** - if all items passed to the control implemented an interface, such as `ICheckableItem`, I could then safely access the same property on each item to populate the TextBox. I'm shying away from this approach as I would like the control to be open about what sort of items it can accept.

**Use an ItemsControl to display the text, instead of generating it in the code-behind** - theoretically I could maintain a list of checked items privately within the control, bind that list to an ItemsControl within the control itself and then somehow bind to the property determined in `DisplayMemberPath`. I don't know if this is even possible, as I think it would have to do some sort of double-binding magic to work, and I don't think that is doable. There are also issues with getting the separator (in this case a comma) to appear if I follow this route.

The options I've listed above don't seem to work, and I can't think of any more possible approaches. Can anyone offer any other solutions?

Here's my code so far:

**XAML**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyNamespace.CheckedListComboBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="30"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="TextBoxHolderGrid">
            <TextBox
                x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=TextBoxHolderGrid}"
                Focusable="False"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
        </Grid>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="PART_ToggleButton"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="-1,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            ClickMode="Press"
            Focusable="False"
            IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            IsTabStop="False">
            <Path
                x:Name="CollapsedArrow"
                Margin="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColor}" />
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup
            x:Name="PART_Popup"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}"
            MaxHeight="{Binding MaxPopupHeight, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Margin="0,-1,0,0"
            IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
            Placement="Bottom"
            StaysOpen="False">
            <Border BorderThickness="1">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColor}" />
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_DropDownScrollViewer" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ItemsControl
                        ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained">
                        <ItemsControl.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightColor}" />
                        </ItemsControl.Background>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class CheckedListComboBox : UserControl
{
    private bool mouseIsOverPopup = false;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CheckedListComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<CheckedListObject>), typeof(CheckedListComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, ItemsSourcePropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDropDownOpenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDropDownOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(CheckedListComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsDropDownOpenChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxPopupHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MaxPopupHeight", typeof(double), typeof(CheckedListComboBox), new PropertyMetadata((double)200));

    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CheckedListObject> ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<CheckedListObject>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool IsDropDownOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDropDownOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDropDownOpenProperty, value); }
    }

    public double MaxPopupHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaxPopupHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxPopupHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    public CheckedListComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void ItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is CheckedListComboBox checkedListComboBox)
        {
            if (e.OldValue != null && e.OldValue is IEnumerable<CheckedListObject> oldItems)
            {
                foreach (var item in oldItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= checkedListComboBox.SubItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.OldValue != null && e.OldValue is INotifyCollectionChanged oldCollection)
            {
                oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= checkedListComboBox.ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
            }

            if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue is IEnumerable<CheckedListObject> newItems)
            {
                foreach (var item in newItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += checkedListComboBox.SubItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged newCollection)
            {
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += checkedListComboBox.ItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
            }

            checkedListComboBox.CalculateComboBoxText();
        }
    }

    private void SubItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IsChecked", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            CalculateComboBoxText();
        }
    }

    private void ItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The bound ItemsSource collection has changed, so we want to unsubscribe any old items
        // from the PropertyChanged event, and subscribe any new ones to this event.

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (oldItem is CheckedListObject item)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= SubItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (newItem is CheckedListObject item)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += SubItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        // We also want to re-calculate the text in the ComboBox, in case any checked items
        // have been added or removed.

        CalculateComboBoxText();
    }

    private void CalculateComboBoxText()
    {
        var checkedItems = ItemsSource?.Where(item => item.IsChecked);

        if (checkedItems?.Any() ?? false)
        {
            PART_TextBox.Text = string.Join(", ", checkedItems.Select(i => i.Item?.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            PART_TextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private static void IsDropDownOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is CheckedListComboBox box)
        {
            if (box.IsDropDownOpen)
            {
                Mouse.Capture(box, CaptureMode.SubTree);
            }
            else
            {
                if (Mouse.Captured?.Equals(box) ?? false)
                {
                    Mouse.Capture(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            var textBoxPoint = e.GetPosition(PART_TextBox);
            var popupPoint = e.GetPosition(PART_Popup.Child);

            var mouseIsOverTextBox = !(textBoxPoint.X < 0 || textBoxPoint.X > PART_TextBox.ActualWidth || textBoxPoint.Y < 0 || textBoxPoint.Y > PART_TextBox.ActualHeight);
            var mouseIsOverPopup = !(popupPoint.X < 0 || popupPoint.X > PART_Popup.Child.RenderSize.Width || popupPoint.Y < 0 || popupPoint.Y > PART_Popup.Child.RenderSize.Height);

            if (mouseIsOverPopup && !mouseIsOverTextBox)
            {
                mouseIsOverPopup = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mouseIsOverPopup = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mouseIsOverPopup = false;
        }

        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDropDownOpen && !mouseIsOverPopup)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }

        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }
}
```

And here's the wrapper class for each of the items.

```
public class CheckedListObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isChecked;
    private object item;

    public CheckedListItem()
    { }

    public CheckedListItem(object item, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public object Item
    {
        get { return item; }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item"));
        }
    }


    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here's how I'm using the control:

```
<p:CheckedListComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <p:CheckedListComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Margin="0,0,6,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </p:CheckedListComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</p:CheckedListComboBox>
```

Comment: As your control has the properties ItemsSource and ItemTemplate, and is supposed to have DisplayMemberPath, why don't you derive it from ItemsControl? Or probably from [Selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector(v=vs.110).aspx)